# Name for block matrices where matrix has same structure as blocks

Tags: matrices, terminology, symmetric-matrices, block-matrices

I have stumbled upon the following matrix

\begin{align} M =
\begin{pmatrix} 
I& A&A\\
A& I &A\\
A&A&I
\end{pmatrix}\,,
\end{align}

where $I$ is the identity matrix and $A$ is defined as,

\begin{align} A =
\begin{pmatrix} 
1& a&a\\
a& 1 &a\\
a&a&1
\end{pmatrix}\,,
\end{align}

with $a$ being a scalar. The structure of the block matrix $M$ mimics the structure of its blocks $A - I$ was wondering if matrices likes these have a particular name?

Comment: Parisi replica matrix?